# Почему происходит дублирование первой страницы при печати сайта, если контент не помещается на одной странице?

Tags: javascript, css, print, печать

Всем, привет!
В интернете нет ответа на этот вопрос.

Чтобы увидеть наглядно можно перейти сюда [service.vspbmebel.ru](http://service.vspbmebel.ru), на вкладку производство, там "Печать оковка" и в модальном окне кликните на печать
Если вы в хроме, то сразу увидите предпросмотр
Сама кнопка просто запускает команду `windows.print()`.

Как вы можете заметить, контент не помещается на одну страницу, но вместо того, чтобы распечататься на несколько, он просто дублирует первую
В это же время, если при печати должна получится всего одна страница *например, редактор двери - печать - печать", то всё ок.

Приведу весь релевантный код:

```
@media print{  
  h1, .constructor-header, .left-options, .main-view, .modal-header, .left-menu, .constructor-wrap{  
    display : none;  
  }  
  .modal-content, .constructor-wrap{  
    border : none;  
  }  
  .form-group{  
    margin-bottom : 0;  
  }  
  body.modal-open{  
    overflow : visible;  
  }  
}  


$(document).on("click", ".modal-header .btn-print", function() {  
  var height;  
  height = $(".modal-content:visible").height();  
  $("body").css('min-height', height); // хак для модальных окон  
  window.print();  
  return false;  
});
```

`page-break-before : always;` кстати, тоже не работает внутри модалки, несмотря на отсутствие флоатов у родителя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас у `.modal` стоит `position: fixed`.
Поможет добавление в `@media print`:

```
.modal { 
    position: relative 
}
```

И в хроме есть эмуляция `@media` запросов на вкладке `Rendering`

Comment: Спасибо большое, это действительно помогло